# Unwanted space in div below responsive background image

Tags: css, responsive-design, background-image

I am re-writing the styling of a web page to make it responsive and to remove the now deprecated use of HTML tables to define overall page structure.  One of the requirements is to include a header panel containing an image which will scale as the display size changes. Initially I have done this with a  container containing a single non-breaking space, but with a background image defined in the CSS:

```
#header {
    background: url(images/cropped_logo_green.jpg) no-repeat; 
    background-size: contain;
    background-color: #333333;
    max-width: 1000px;
    height: 19.25vw;
    }
```

The specification height: 19.25vw; achieves more or less the result I am looking for, but I have two problems with it.  First, the use of the vw spec is only recognized by the very latest browsers, and secondly, as the display width exceeds 1000px, the height of the div continues to increase, leaving an empty rectangular space below the image. Is there any way of achieving the responsive scaling I need (a) without using vw and (b) avoiding the empty space below the div?

The screenshot available at www.skogen.co.uk/pix/screenshot.jpg shows the offending div outlined using element inspection, and clearly indicates the extra space below the jpeg image when the browser window width exceeds the value giving the maximum width of the header (which is set at 95% of the page width).

Comment: Can you send a url of your web-site or image of the problem?

Comment: To clarify, HTML tables are not deprecated, but should be reserved for tabular (e.g. data) content

Comment: Are you able to simply save a taller image? If that width:height ratio needs to be maintained, you could use jQuery to maintain the ratio and specify a new height when resized.

Comment: Did you try setting a max-height which is the actual height of the background image?

Comment: 99tharun: Replacing "height: 19.25vw" by "max-height: 200px" results in a VERY small version of the image which maintains its aspect ratio but is only approximately as wide as the first column in the lower area.  Even with both present, in either possible order, the behaviour is the same as with the vw version alone.

Comment: Correction - with apologies for any confusion - to my last comment.  I omitted one of the semi-colons in my CSS file by mistake, and can now confirm that adding "max-height: 200px" has corrected the problem completely.  I will look into further possibilities to avoid "vw" specifications when I have time tomorrow.